# What to do with old questions linked to missing screencast?

Tags: discussion, editing

Reviewing some of the old question I find questions with missing screencast (the link point to a missing file).

What are we supposed to do with these questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a bit of general advice with links:

- update the link if you can, but
- always include as much useful information as is feasible directly in the answer to avoid exactly this problem.

Of course, linked videos may go bad without recourse. StackExchange has it's own imgur (I think) for uploaded pictures, so that can be an alternative when the animated nature is less important (I'm not sure if GIFs count in this respect).

Comment: If we review a question with a missing screencast should we remove the screencast or should we delete the question or do nothing?

Comment: Generally I would probably vote-to-close unless the question can be understood without the screencast. But also a comment asking the author to update the links, wait a few days, then VtC with a comment about why—this might be more polite.